# The use of "respectively"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I am wondering which of these following sentences are right.

1. We applied active learning algorithms in spectral and sample spaces, respectively.
2. We applied active learning algorithms in the spectral space and sample space, respectively.

Comment: Either works, but neither makes much sense.  "Respectively" is used, in this sort of statement, when A, B, and C, are applied to X, Y, and Z, respectively.  If you applied one thing to all then there's no relationship to respect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hot Licks said in a comment, you wouldn't use *respectively* here because you're not pairing up equal numbers of items from two lists. An appropriate usage would be something like:

> We applied frob and fnord algorithms to the spectral and sample spaces, respectively.

This means you applied frob to the spectral space and fnord to the sample space, but *not* frob to the sample space or fnord to the spectral space.

Comment: Thanks! We applied A  and B  to the spectral and sample spaces, respectively.